# Can we create a biological version of humanoid robot that don't carries DNA?

Tags: biology, creature-design

It looks human, feels human, can walk and run like us and can even argue with us, but it do not possess DNA. Is it possible to create this homunculus?

Comment: Well seeing as how DNA is what makes us... us, I would go out on a limb and say no. (By the way, not that it matters, I didn't vote on your question.)

Comment: How do you define "biological"?

Comment: @sumelic: it is a living thing.

Comment: How do you define "living"? (It seems likely to me that the most important part is just what you say in the question: that it looks and feels like a normal human.)

Comment: @MattWoodspirit: I want to make a robot out out living tissues that can die like us and I don't want to make a clone of myself. Anyway I welcome down vote and appreciate much if accompanied with comments.

Comment: @sumelic: yes that's is what I said everything about this homologous is human except the genetic blueprint, is it possible?

Comment: The hard part for me when trying to answer this question is that all macroscopic life that I know of possesses DNA. The genetic blueprint is not the same for all lifeforms, but all of them have some kind. It seems to me that to create this creature, it would be necessary to design a complete substitute for DNA, and I'm confused why scientists would do that rather than going the much easier route of using DNA, which already exists.

Comment: Does it have to be DNA or is any "blueprint" material forbidden?

Comment: Sure, you *can*, this is your universe, you can do whatever you like to further the story. I think the question is more along the lines of, how might you plausibly explain that without a simple hand-wave? That's where the question gets trickier to answer and feels a little like overt idea generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNA stores information to build proteins necessary for body function. You need some information for basic biological function and robots firmware, and thus way to store it.
If you want to make robot biological, I assume you don't want it to have mechanical/electronic memory either. If it wont use DNA for it either, you need to make up some new for of memory that will take on this function.

Answer (score 0):

Currently all biological 'living' materials that we are aware of have DNA/RNA.  So if you want to cover your robot in 'flesh' that isn't some kind of rubber/plastic/neoprene etc. then either you have to invent an alternative to DNA or it will have DNA.  It of course does not have to be human DNA that you use but some kind of DNA would be simplest if you want a 'biological' robot.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Yes, as RNA can perform any function that DNA can.

I'm not sure why you would want to though, as DNA is used by cells as it is much more stable than RNA, unless that instability is the entire point.